# Codeigniter Undefined property: App\Controllers\Home::$load cannot load models or views

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to use

```
$this->load->model("Test_model");
```

In the codeigniter framework, I receive the following error: Undefined property: App\Controllers\Home::$load

I really don't get why this happens, it also happens when I try to use views.

Comment: can you put a bit context around your question? where are you using this line? if it is from an controller or somewhere outside?

Comment: Have you tried installing https://github.com/topdown/phpStorm-CC-Helpers into your project?

Comment: It appeared to be that I was using Codeigniter 3 syntax, but installed the Codeigniter 4